# how to start the bonjour service on linux

Tags: linux, bonjour, mdns

I have installed the bonjour mDNSResponder on my linux pc , and able run the mdns deamon .

I have posted my web server on the PC (192.168.1.111) which is connected to wifi router . now I need to publish this service using bonjour .

Could anyone help me to do the same .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zeroconf services (except IPv4LL) on Linux are provided by [**Avahi**](http://avahi.org/). Use the distro's normal service mechanisms to start the Avahi daemon. In order to announce services running on the web server you'll need to use something like [mod_dnssd](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/mod_dnssd/) that talks to it.